# React-Native componentWillUnmount is not calling on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I have **componentWillUnmount** lifecycle on my root component. When a user closes the app (swiping from background) this lifecycle is executing on the Android but not on iOS. Is this a known issue? 
    ***I'm not posting any of the code as it is only for discussion*.**